# How could I simply this xpath so that xmlstartlet works with it?

Tags: xml, command-line, xpath, xmlstarlet

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -c "//str[@name="id" and .="http://localhost:8080/index.html"]/../str[@name="doc-norm"]"/value results.xml
```

My understanding is that `xmlstarlet` doesn't fully support xpath expressions. Is there any other command-line tool that does BTW?

```
<doc>
    <str name="id">http://localhost:8080/index.html</str>
    <str name="doc-norm">6</str>
</doc>
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant XML snippet as well?

Comment: @Tomalak - sorry, tryin to post the shortest example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to return the `6` from your example?

I don't have xmlstarlet to test this on, but try this XPath:

`//*[str[@name='id']='http://localhost:8080/index.html']/str[@name='doc-norm']`

This should return the value of a `str` element that has a `name` attribute with a value of `doc-norm` when its parent element has a child `str` element that has an `id` attribute with a value of `http://localhost:8080/index.html`. (I hope that makes sense!)

I should also add that if you know what the level of the parent element is, try to avoid using the `//`. Something like `/doc[str[@name='id']='http://localhost:8080/index.html']/str[@name='doc-norm']` would be more efficient.

**UPDATE**

I downloaded xmlstartlet to test and it works fine, however it returns the entire `str` element. If you want the text only, add `text()` to the end of the XPath:

`//*[str[@name='id']='http://localhost:8080/index.html']/str[@name='doc-norm']/text()`

Comment: +1 for a good answer. I guess that the nested quotes could have been the reason of the OP's problem.